# A misnomer, yet I too have a taste

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> I’m made of two parts, you see 
>   Where the first part is a tree 
>   Whose trunk can be used for furniture 
>   Its leaves may be used to brew tea
>
> The other is from another tree 
>   Whose growth is not fast-paced 
>   Together, I relate not to a tree 
>   A misnomer, yet I too have a taste

So tell me, what could I be?

Comment: ..... Never did I expect there to be so many different types of tree leaf teas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> the **pineapple**

```
I’m made of two parts, you see
Where the first part is a tree
Whose trunk can be used for furniture
Its leaves may be used to brew tea
```

> The first of its two parts, **pine**, is a tree whose wood is frequently used in furniture making. ["Pine needles can be simmered into a tea that’s rich in vitamin C, and also happens to be pretty tasty."](https://practicalselfreliance.com/medicinal-trees/)

```
The other is from another tree
Whose growth is not fast-paced
```

> The second part, **apple**, is a type of tree that generally has a medium growth rate - or, more to the point, is not considered to be a fast growth rate (["The designation slow means the plant grows 12” or less per year; medium refers to 13 to 24” of growth per year; and fast to 25” or greater"](https://www.arborday.org/trees/treeGuide/growth.cfm), and most apple trees are considered "medium" growth rate on this scale—though there are indeed some that are classed as "fast").

```
Together, I relate not to a tree
A misnomer, yet I too have a taste
```

> Pineapple plants are shrubs, not trees.
>  It is misnamed in that, originally, a 'pine apple' was what we now call a pine cone - which would indeed be related to a tree. But ... Because English ... we (quite anomalously) now call the fruit and its plant a "pineapple" because of the fruit’s general resemblance to a pine cone, whereas most other languages use "ananas" or something related. See also [Why is “pineapple” in English but “ananas” in all other languages?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/134659).
>  Pineapples, of course, have their own taste, one I quite enjoy.

Comment: Nicely explained!